# How to properly encode UTF-8

Tags: flash, utf-8

I have a simple text file saved as UTF-8.

In this file I have a string containing

```
Côte-des-neiges
```

But whenever I load this in flash and trace it out I get

```
C√¥te-des-neiges
```

Confused as to why this happens....

Comment: Looks like interpreting UTF-8 as some legacy single-byte-character-set. Not sure which one.

Comment: Try to verify the charset (encoding) of your text file.

Comment: You can also use something like [this](http://www.webtoolkit.info/actionscript-utf8.html).

Comment: thanks...looks like a good resource